# Pygame: Blitting a text surface onto another surface continuously

Tags: python, pygame

I created a program that displays a text: "0 $" and when we click on it that increases the money and displays a new image.

If you do not understand look at the pictures:

[image]

You see that the first image "0 $" is displayed correctly, but when I click on the mouse, the first text persists and the new text is drawn over it.

Here is my code:

```py
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
     
    #Init pygame
    pygame.init()
    window_size = (960,480)
    window = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size,RESIZABLE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Space Shooter")
     
    #COLOR
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    BLACK =  (  0, 0, 0)
     
    #Variables
    money = 0
     
    #Font
    calibri_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri",50)
     
    #Load image,surface
    light = pygame.image.load("light.png")
    bg = pygame.image.load("space.jpg").convert()
    plane = pygame.image.load("plane.png").convert_alpha()
     
    #Transfo sprite
    light = pygame.transform.scale(light,(500,550))
    plane = pygame.transform.scale(plane,(1000,550))
     
    #Text
    money_text_surface = calibri_font.render(str(money) +" $",True, WHITE)
     
    #Rect
    money_text_rect = money_text_surface.get_rect()
    position_light= rotate_light = light.get_rect()
    position_plane = plane.get_rect()
     
    #Position
    money_text_rect.centerx =750
    money_text_rect.centery =425
     
    #other
    plane_speed = (0,0)
     
    #functions
    def move(speed, acceleration):
        vx, vy = speed
        ax, ay = acceleration
        speed = (vx + ax, vy + ay)
        return speed
     
     
    #Event loop
    continue = True
    while continue:
        #FPS limit
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(90)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                    continue = False
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    plane_s = move(plane_speed, (10,0))
                elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                    plane_speed = move(plane_speed, (-10,0))
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    plane_speed = move(plane_speed, (0,-10))
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    plane_speed = move(plane_speed, (0,10))
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    plane_speed = move(plane_speed, (-10,0))
                elif event.key == K_UP:
                    plane_speed = move(plane_speed, (0,10))
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    plane_speed = move(plane_speed, (0,-10))
                elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                    plane_speed = move(plane_speed, (10,0))
     
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    money +=10
                    money_text_surface = calibri_font.render(str(money) +" $",True,WHITE)
     
     
            i=0
            for loop in range(1):
                rotate_light = pygame.transform.rotate(light, 1+i)
                i+= 1
     
     
     
        #Logic
        vx, vy = plane_vitesse
        position_plane.left += vx
        position_plane.top += vy
     
     
        #Display
        bg.blit(money_text_surface, money_text_rect)
        window.blit(fond, (0,0))
        window.blit(rotate_light, position_light)
        window.blit(avion, position_plane)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your image into the actual post - some of us can't follow the link to the image due to restrictions on internal networks.

Comment: Hello paul, i can't sorry :( I need 10 reputation on the site x)

Comment: anyone? plz ::::

Comment: So you just want to update the number on the surface?

Comment: yes it is-----------------------

Comment: I think we need to edit your question, because the title says something different. But first tell me if the code in my answer does what you want.

Comment: THANKS ur code does what i want !! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to blit the money onto a money background image/surface. You have to create a copy of the original background and then blit the newly rendered text onto it, otherwise you would blit more and more text surfaces on the same original surface.

In this example I do that in the `render_money` function and return the copy (`money_surf`) with the current money on it. Then I assign it to the `money_surf` variable in the `main` function where I blit it. If the user clicks on the image, I check if the mouse pos collides with the `money_rect`, increase the money and re-render the money surface.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
CALIBRI_FONT = pg.font.SysFont('Calibri', 50)
# The money background surface.
# Replace these two lines with your loaded image.
MONEY_SURF = pg.Surface((150, 70))
MONEY_SURF.fill((0, 60, 120))


def render_money(money):
    """Blit the money onto a copy of the money background image."""
    money_text_surf = CALIBRI_FONT.render(str(money)+' $', True, (230, 250, 250))
    # Make a copy of your background image, so that the original is not modified.
    money_surf = MONEY_SURF.copy()
    money_surf.blit(money_text_surf, (10, 10))
    return money_surf


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()

    money = 0
    money_surf = render_money(money)
    # This rect serves as the blit position and for the collision detection.
    money_rect = money_surf.get_rect(topleft=(100, 200))

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # Check if the rect collides with the mouse pos (event.pos).
                if money_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    money += 10
                    # Now re-render the money surface.
                    money_surf = render_money(money)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        screen.blit(money_surf, money_rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```